# SAS Datetime Proc SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, sas

Hello I was wondering how would you write this code in a `PROC SQL` vs the `data step` I wrote below. I am trying to reduce the code, the data is initially in a text file unfortunately the datetime when changed to a `CHAR`(import wizard) is a length of 9 vs 8(computed column) which is the default, hence why i change it in the first data step. I eventually get the results I want but I would like to see if SQL could provide a more efficient solution.

```
data WORK.CNE_RESI;
  SET WORK.cneres_41;
  FORMAT RPTDATE_2 $CHAR9.;
  IF rptdate = '1/5/2015' THEN  RPTDATE_2 = '1/9/2015'; 
  ELSE IF RPTDATE_2 = "" THEN  RPTDATE_2=rptdate ;
RUN;

data WORK.CNE_RESI_2;
  SET WORK.CNE_RESI;
  FORMAT RPTDATE_3 MMDDYY10.;
  RPTDATE = input(RPTDATE_2, MMDDYY10.);
RUN;
```

Comment: I would fix the import from the text file first and I would assume you would need a CHAR10, 12/31/2015 would be 10 characters? At any rate you should import it directly as a date value instead.

Comment: Is RPTDATE_2 a new variable or it's already existed in dataset cneres_41?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it but I had a go.

```
%let olddate = 1/5/2015;
%let newdate = 1/9/2015;


proc sql;

create table WORK.CNE_RESI_2 as
select a.*,
case when rptdate = "&olddate" then "&newdate"
else rptdate
end as RPTDATE_2 format=$char9.,
input(case when rptdate = "&olddate" then "&newdate"
else rptdate
end,mmddyy10.) as RPTDATE_3 format=mmddyy10.
from WORK.cneres_41 a;
quit;
```

Of course if you didn't actually need the variable rptdate_2 and were just using that to change format then this should work.

```
proc sql;
    create table WORK.CNE_RESI_2 as
    select a.*,
    input(case when rptdate = "&olddate" then "&newdate"
          else rptdate
          end,mmddyy10.) as RPTDATE_3 format=mmddyy10.
from WORK.cneres_41 a;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ultimate question is:

> I eventually get the results I want but I would like to see if SQL
>   could provide a more efficient solution.

The reason that your DATA steps seem inefficient is that you make two complete passes over the data.  There's no reason for that in this case, and a single DATA step is likely to be at least as efficient as SQL for your example.  Also, placing the `format` statement above the `set` statement will redefine the length of `rptdate` without the need for an intermediate variable.  With these thoughts in mind, your two DATA steps could be more efficiently written as:

```
data WORK.CNE_RESI;
    format rptdate $char10. rptdate_n mmddyy10.; 
    set WORK.cneres_41;

    if rptdate = '1/05/2015' then rptdate = '1/09/2015';
    rptdate_n = input(rptdate, ?? MMDDYY10.);
run;
```